# @Html.Partial does not render the view when the code is within foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

I have below code for displaying a partial view,
but when the application is executed the partial view is not displayed.

I appreciate any suggestions.

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
 {
     foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        <div id="assignment_@item.AssignmentId" class="row">
             @Html.Partial("_AssignmentSubmissionsPartial", item);                                  
        </div>
        <hr>
     }
  }
```

If I have to use the above code with RenderPartial how can I use it?

Comment: Does the partial view expect an object of the type of your item? Also have you set up a partial view controller for that partial view?

Comment: Yeah the item object is used to display on the screen it is used by the partialview. I didnt get what you mean by partialview controller for the partial view ?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in the partial view, does that hit?

Comment: Side note: code will likely produce invalid HTML with duplicate IDs - check if `assignment_@item.AssignmentId` written directly to output producing rows with the same ID and possibly breaking your code that show/hides rows by ID.

Comment: Please share the code of the partial view also.

Comment: Yes the break point his partial view and complete partial view code is executed but the out put of partial view doesnt appear

Comment: I have created another thred in stackoverflow with detailed information please check this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719525/mvc-partial-views-fail-when-rendered-with-looping-statements